# Extract number in Preg_match_all of jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, regex, curl, preg-match-all

Just trying to extract the second td (which is a number) of the table that is, the value of **235**. Values of numbers change dynamically.

```
jQuery('.content').append('<tr><td>Volume1</td><td>56</td><td>123</td></tr>');
jQuery('.content').append('<tr><td>Volume2</td><td>235</td><td>789</td></tr>');
```

In php I have this:

```
if(preg_match_all("/jQuery\(\'.content\'\).append\((\'<tr><td>Volume2</td><td>(.*?)\')\);/", $result))
```

Of course it does not work because I don't know how to use regex in html tags. Please help

**Edit**: 
The solution must be in php because jQuery receive from another server using the curl php.

Comment: Where is `$result` coming from, and why would it contain jQuery code?

Comment: So... do you want all the numbers (ie 56, 123, 235, 789)? or just where the 235 is?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$(".content tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)").text();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zuhb9/

If you have multiple class content then you need to loop through all of them:

```
$(".content").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find("tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)").text());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zuhb9/1/

Comment: The solution must be in php